# Is New York City Council considering making public urination legal?

Tags: united-states, law

The [*Political Insider* claims](http://www.thepoliticalinsider.com/40005-2/)

According to the article:

> The left-wingers who run New York City are about to make it 100% legal
>   to urinate in public.
>
> Why? Because many blacks and minorities have been fined or arrested
>   for it. They would rather legalize this disgusting behavior than
>   enforce basic rules of public sanitation.
>
> Urinating and drinking in public would no longer be treated as crimes
>   under a package of bills New York’s City Council will consider to ease
>   enforcement of quality-of-life offenses that lawmakers say clog the
>   courts and have been disproportionately enforced against minorities.
>
> The council scheduled a Jan. 25 hearing on the proposed laws, which are supported by Council Speaker Melissa Mark-Viverito, a
>   majority of her 50 colleagues and Police Commissioner Bill Bratton.
>   The proposal would remove the possibility of permanent criminal
>   records for public urination and violating park rules, mostly treating
>   them as civil offenses, along with public drinking, littering and
>   excessive noise.
>
> Such low-level offenses have left the city with more than 1.2 million active warrants, according to a fact sheet distributed by the
>   council Wednesday.

Any truth in this?

Comment: I don't think an answer should attempt to determine the political likelihood of it proceeding; that it is being proposed (if true) should be a sufficient answer.

Comment: Does this question fall foul of any rules about motivations?

Comment: I've edited to address the above two issues.

Comment: "disproportionately enforced" against a group doesn't mean the group does it more. (Re the original title)

Answer (score 14):

This is an opinion piece that oversteps what its sources say.

The article references [Crain's](http://www.crainsnewyork.com/article/20160121/POLITICS/160129977/city-council-mulls-decriminalizing-quality-of-life-offenses) as a source.

The source article makes it clear that the proposal will NOT make public urination "100% legal", but will treat them as civil, rather than criminal, offences.

(Emphasis mine.)

> Urinating and drinking in public would **no longer be treated as crimes** under a package of bills New York’s City Council will consider to ease enforcement of quality-of-life offenses that lawmakers say clog the courts and have been disproportionately enforced against minorities.
>
> The council scheduled a Jan. 25 hearing on the proposed laws, which are supported by Council Speaker Melissa Mark-Viverito, a majority of her 50 colleagues and Police Commissioner Bill Bratton. The proposal would remove the possibility of permanent criminal records for public urination and violating park rules, **mostly treating them as civil offenses**, along with public drinking, littering and excessive noise.